# Amazon S3 bucket listing using HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This question seems to have been asked before, but I am doing it a different way and so I am posting this since I can't find a specific question that addressed this. Is there a way to get a list of files (actually just the latest file) in a public Amazon bucket without the use of special tools or Amazon CLI, etc? I am not experienced with this whatsoever and after 3 hours I am ready to pull my hair out. I have a simple project where I need the latest file in a bucket but I do not know the filename. (Weather radar data). This is the *only* requirement - and I do have a small amount of programming knowledge but it seems I could not figure out the python/Amazon tools so I am just trying to find an easier route as I am rapidly running out of time.  I am using Windows and command-line tools. On a similar host, I was pulling the data from a server by using wget and parsing the index.html file using a simple C++ console app I wrote to get the filename, then launching wget to download the file since the filename was easily found in the index.

With Amazon I can't seem to figure this out.

This is the main listing : https://s3.amazonaws.com/noaa-nexrad-level2/index.html

Since the filenames are listed by date, then radar site - I can figure most of the URL out. The example filename would be:

https://noaa-nexrad-level2.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/08/07/KEWX/KEWX20180807_094339_V06

For a more precise example - I need the latest file for https://noaa-nexrad-level2.s3.amazonaws.com/2018/08/07/KEWX.

If I could get the XML returned of a directory, I could do it by using the method I did before... but I can't seem to figure that out.

I would be OK with writing a simple program to do this, even if I had to learn some python (it seems to be the most popular way), but I don't understand what I am doing regarding AWS authentication, buckets, etc. and have wasted way too much time on this to start over yet again unless I get some serious help. I hope to find some assistance. I am not trying to be lazy, I am just running out of time and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some form of programmatic handling of the results, either in PowerShell or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

This seems to work:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket noaa-nexrad-level2 --prefix 2018/08/07/KEWX/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text

2018/08/07/KEWX/KEWX20180807_234734_V06
```

It's basically saying: *Sort by LastModified, return the last record, only show the Key (filename)*

(This worked on a Mac. You might need some fiddling with the quotes on Windows.)

Some good videos about the AWS CLI:

- [AWS re:Invent 2017: AWS CLI: 2017 and Beyond (DEV307) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8IyScUGuGI&feature=youtu.be)
- [AWS re:Invent 2016: The Effective AWS CLI User (DEV402) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc1dHtWa9-Q&feature=youtu.be)

The [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) is also very useful for understanding how to use `--query` parameters.

Comment: Yes, I did have to change the quotes from ' to " and the script ran without errors, though all it did was run in a continuous loop and never showed output. I am not sure why this is so difficult for me. I seemed to have installed the CLI correctly but I think theres is something I am just not "getting". Perhaps it is because I am trying to do something I think is simple but I have too little knowledge with this, so whenever I hit a little hiccup I can no longer continue. Your script is exactly what I am looking for if I could just get it to work. It loops continuously- both CLI and Powershell

Comment: *OK* This is working! It outputs the filename needed on the screen (just as yours did, I just had an authentication issue.) The shows output argument is -text... so did it also write the filename in a text file somewhere? I do not see it in the current directory I am running it in. Now that I can see the data, I am very close. I need to somehow get this in a text document. I have scavenged online and I still can't figure this out, but I am so close now.

Comment: I have now figured this out completely, with what you wrote and online research. I needed to add " > filename" at the end. Thank you for your assistance! I look forward to getting more comfortable with CLI as I will need in the coming months.

Comment: I've added links to some great AWS CLI sessions from AWS re:Invent.

Comment: Thank you - I did not realize your profession until just now. It's no wonder you are so helpful.